# turn pdfximage/pdflastximagepages into a function and use in tikz : ERROR: Missing number, treated as zero.

Tags: macros

I feel a bit stupid not to be able to solve this problem, but I can't find a way to turn the following command, usefull to get the number of pages in a pdf : `\pdfximage{mypdf.tex} \the\pdflastximagepages` into an actual command so that I can just write `\pdfximage{images.pdf}` in a `\foreach` loop. And if someone can explain me why the first two examples works but not the last one, I'd be really interested.

Thanks!

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\nbpagepdf}[1]{\pdfximage{#1}\the\pdflastximagepages}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
  %% Ok:
  The number of pages is: \nbpagepdf{images.pdf} !
  %% Ok:
  \pdfximage{images.pdf}
  \foreach \ov in {1,...,\the\pdflastximagepages}{
    \includegraphics<\ov>[page=\ov]{images.pdf}
  }
  %% Not ok:
  \foreach \ov in {1,...,\nbpagepdf{images.pdf}}{
    \includegraphics<\ov>[page=\ov]{images.pdf}
  }
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Error:

```
ERROR: Missing number, treated as zero.

--- TeX said ---
<to be read again> 
                   \pdfximage 
l.10   }
```

Comment: `\nbpagepdf` is not a number, it only *outputs* at the end a number. you can't use it in a context where tex needs a real number.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer : so what can I do to embed everything into a single function ?

Comment: Nothing (at least not with pdflatex, with lualatex it would be perhaps possible to write a lua function). It won't work like you want it to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a suitable macro that first does `\pdfximage`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\includepdfpages}[1]{%
  \pdfximage{#1}%
  \foreach \ov in {1,...,\the\pdflastximagepages}{%
    \includegraphics<\ov>[page=\ov]{#1}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \includepdfpages{tobiasimages.pdf}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

The file has ten images and this is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, even if it's not exactly what I was asking for, it should do the job most of the time. But I still don't understand what make it fondamentally different from others macros? For example I would expect that using an `\edef` would solve the issue, but it does not work... If you have some good explanation for that it would be really nice.