# pgffor in beamer does not compile with \onslide

Tags: beamer, overlays, includegraphics, compilation-error, pgffor

## What I Want

I'm creating a presentation with pdflatex and the beamer documentclass.

In an external program I created a stepwise graphic. The graphic is one PDF file where each page in that PDF is a single step.

I want to show the steps of this graphics one at a time. The graphic for each step should replace the graphic of the previous step. This is essentially what `\multiinclude` from `xmpmulti.sty` does, except that all steps are taken from a single PDF file.

I did so with the following tex code:

```
\begin{frame}
    Content before
    \pause

    \begin{overprint}
        \onslide<+|handout:0>\includegraphics[page=1]{img}
        \onslide<+|handout:0>\includegraphics[page=2]{img}
        \onslide<+-|handout:1>\includegraphics[page=3]{img}
    \end{overprint}
    \onslide<+->

    Content after
\end{frame}
```

[image: presentation slides as they should be]

As I want to include many such stepwise graphics I wanted to automate this process with a for loop and later with a command. However, I cannot seem to get it right.

## What I Have

At the moment I have the following

```
\nonstopmode
\pdfsuppresswarningpagegroup=1

\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgffor}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \pdfximage{img.pdf}
    \newcounter{laststep}
    \setcounter{laststep}{\pdflastximagepages}
    \begin{overprint}
    \foreach \x in {1,...,\value{laststep}} {
        %\onslide<+|handout:0>
        \includegraphics[page=\x]{img}
    }
    \end{overprint}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

To make this example self contained: Here is the output of [`base64 img.pdf`](https://pastebin.com/GqdNYEyw). Copy-paste this into `base64 -d > img.pdf` to the get the file or use an [online service](https://base64.guru/converter/decode/file).

The code as shown compiles and includes all steps of `img.pdf` at the same time, but when I uncomment `\onslide<+|handout:0>`  I get the following error over and over again. pdflatex runs endlessly.

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   p
l.19 \end{frame}
```

I spent several hours trying to automate inclusion of these stepwise graphics. In other attempts I also used other loop macros such as `forloop` but nothing worked so far. This is my best attempt so far.

## Question

How can I include a stepwise graphic from a single PDF? Either by fixing the broken `\foreach` or by using a different approach or even existing solution in form of a package.

Comment: Try replacing the loop by `\newcounter{iloop}
 \setcounter{iloop}{0}
    \loop\stepcounter{iloop}
        \onslide<+|handout:0>
        \includegraphics[page=\number\value{iloop}]{img}
    \ifnum\value{iloop}<\value{laststep}\repeat`. BTW, your question is very similar to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/445916.

Comment: The suggested loop resulted in the errors 2×`Command \c@laststep already defined` and 2×`Command \c@iloop already defined`.

Comment: My bad, `\newcounter{iloop} ` should not be inside the frame, and the same statement applies to `\newcounter{laststep}`.

Comment: Sorry – I found no good file hoster to share `img.pdf`, so you have to coope with the base64 representation. But the content is irrelevant. You can take any pdf you have lying around.

Comment: Yes, I figured that. ;-) The loop does work if one does the `\newcounter`s before the frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the user [Schrödinger's cat](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/515683/99001) I was able to complete my command.
I ran into another small problem, where the next `\pause` after my command would pause twice, but I fixed it by modifying the counter `beamerpauses`.

The final command is:

```
\nonstopmode
\pdfsuppresswarningpagegroup=1
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\newcounter{laststep}
\newcounter{step}
\newcommand{\stepwisegraphics}[1]{%
    \pdfximage{#1.pdf}
    \setcounter{laststep}{\pdflastximagepages}
    \setcounter{step}{1}
    \begin{overprint}
        \loop
            \onslide<+|handout:0>
            \includegraphics[page=\thestep]{#1}
            \stepcounter{step}\ifnum\value{step}<\value{laststep}\repeat
        \addtocounter{beamerpauses}{-1} % workaround mystic double pause
        \pause
        \includegraphics[page=\thestep]{#1}
    \end{overprint}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    top\par
    \pause \stepwisegraphics{img}
    \pause middle 1\par
    \pause middle 2\par
    \pause \stepwisegraphics{img}
    \pause bottom
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: resulting slides animated]

Comment: Maybe `\resetcounteronoverlays{step}` also works? (I didn't try.) (+1)

Comment: I don't think so. The documentation of `\resetcounteronoverlays` states »*After you have invoked this command, the value of the specified counter will be **the same on all slides** of every frame.*«. However, `beamerpauses` must change, or else I wouldn't get a step-by-step presentation.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me (I created my own `img.pdf` with different contents).

```
\nonstopmode
\pdfsuppresswarningpagegroup=1

\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\newcounter{laststep}
\newcounter{iloop}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \pdfximage{img.pdf}
    \setcounter{laststep}{\pdflastximagepages}
    \begin{overprint}
    \setcounter{iloop}{0}
    \loop\stepcounter{iloop}
        \onslide<+|handout:0>
        \includegraphics[page=\number\value{iloop}]{img}
    \ifnum\value{iloop}<\value{laststep}\repeat
    \end{overprint}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Moving the counter declaration worked for your loop. Pfg's `\foreach` still failed, but that doesn't matter – I'm happy to have one dependency less. ¶ Do you know why declaring a counter inside `frame` fails?

Comment: @Socowi Yes. If you use `\pause` or something in a frame, this means that the code gets executed more than once. Therefore `\newcounter` gets executed more than once, which triggers an error.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. Thank you for all the help!